# More GCC link time issues: undefined reference to main

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, linker

I'm writing software for a Cortex-A8 processor and I have to write some ARM assembly code to access specific registers. I'm making use of the GNU compilers and related toolchains; these tools are installed on the processor board (Freescale i.MX515) with Ubuntu. I make a connection to it from my host PC (Windows) using WinSCP and the PuTTY terminal.

As usual I started with a simple C project having **main.c** and **functions.s**. I **compile** the main.c using **GCC**, **assemble** the functions.s using **as** and **link** the generated object files using once again **GCC**, but I get strange errors during this process.

**An important finding -**

Meanwhile, I found out that my assembly code may have some issues because when I individually assemble it using the command `as -o functions.o functions.s` and try running the generated **functions.o** using `./functions.o` command, the Bash shell is failing to recognize this file as an executable (on pressing tab functions.o is not getting selected/PuTTY is not highlighting the file).

Can anyone suggest what's happening here? Are there any **specific options I have to send, to GCC** during the linking process? The errors I see are strange and beyond my understanding, I don't understand to what the GCC is referring.

I'm pasting here the contents of main.c, functions.s, the Makefile and the list of errors.

### Help, please!!!

**Latest errors included after the makefile was edited as suggested here **

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/Project/Others/helloworld$ make
gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a8 main.c
as -mcpu=cortex-a8 -o functions.o functions.s
gcc -o hello main.o functions.o
functions.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../crt1.o:init.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

---

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**functions.s**

```
* Main program */
    .equ      STACK_TOP, 0x20000800
    .text
    .global _start
    .syntax unified

_start:
    .word STACK_TOP, start
    .type start, function

start:
    movs  r0, #10
    movs  r1, #0
    .end
```

**Makefile**

```
all: hello

hello: main.o functions.o
    gcc hello -o main.o functions.o
```

-- hello was included here after suggested here by guys at Stack Overflow, but the problem still persists; I still get the same errors.

```
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a8 main.c

functions.o: functions.s
    as -mcpu=cortex-a8 -o functions.o functions.s
```

**Errors**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/Project/Others/helloworld$ make
gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a8 main.c
as -mcpu=cortex-a8 -o functions.o functions.s
gcc -o main.o functions.o
functions.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../crt1.o:init.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
init.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Comment: The build log suggests that you are targeting Linux.  Is this intentional or were you intending a 'bare-metal' target?  It appears by targeting Linux, `init.o` is being implicitly linked, and that already contains the symbol `_start`.

That is probably a different issue however to the missing `main()`.

Comment: Clifford I made the changes to the makefile but getting errors regarding the init, I don't know how. :( I have run a very big application on this board without any problems this problem has started when I included the Assembly code.

Answer (score 8):

In the makefile:

```
hello: main.o functions.o
    gcc -o main.o functions.o
```

should be:

```
hello: main.o functions.o
    gcc -o hello main.o functions.o
```

As it stands, you are linking functions.o, but not main.o, and producing an output executable called main.o, which is overwriting your existing main.o.

Comment: Hi Neil, I made the change and I still see similar errors, I'm pasting them below -

ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Documents/Project/Others/helloworld$ make
gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-a8 main.c
as -mcpu=cortex-a8 -o functions.o functions.s
gcc -o hello main.o functions.o
functions.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/../../../crt1.o:init.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1

Comment: @vikram Edit the new info into your question. It looks to me as if the RT library is defining _start as well.

Comment: Neil I have included the new list of errors, the init is somehow getting invoked I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
hello: main.o functions.o
    gcc -o main.o functions.o
```

be

```
hello: main.o functions.o
    gcc -o hello main.o functions.o
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bigbohne suggests, gcc is trying to link in the standard runtime library.  Try adding the -nostdlib option to your gcc call:

```
gcc -nostdlib -o hello main.o functions.o
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that has something to do with the Runtime library the gcc is linking at the end.

And in **this** library there already is a "_start".

I think you have to compile without "std library". but than you wont have printf,getchar and all the other useful stuff.

Comment: Bigbonhne, I commented out the stdio.h and stdlib.h, but no changes, I  once again get complaints about the multiple definitions to _start.

Answer (score 0):

Normally execution of a program compiled with `gcc` starts in the function called `_start` (in a startup file provided by `gcc`), which calls `main`.

If you are supplying your own `_start`, you should pass `-nostdlib` to `gcc` when linking. This disables all default startup files and all default libraries. You should therefore also explicitly provide any libraries you need such as libc and libgcc.

Your `_start` however does not call `main`, so it is unclear why you bother to provide `main` and the `.c` file at all.

`gcc -o main.o functions.o` is a mistake, it should be `gcc -o main main.o functions.o`, but this will not fix the problem described above.